# How to move text of a banner image while sliding?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, banner

I have to make a banner slider exactly similar like this:

https://kasian.com/

how can I make letters move like this with "View project" button?

Comment: CSS transitions. On mouse hover, do a transition on multiple elements such as the text & arrow.

Comment: If you have an existing example... just inspect the source? What's stopping you from doing that?